# PyQt4: Load large data sets in QStandardItemModel

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qstandarditemmodel

Well, in my current project, the records are loaded from a database directly into `QStandardItemModel` and then view via `QTreeView()`. Everything works fine too. But I thought about the ram-memory. I think that the `QStandardItemModel`, including records, will be loaded into ram-memory. Similar to the data structure (for instance `list`), right? But what happens when I have large data sets? I read in [Qt Documentation: Fetch More Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html) that I have to add items to the model in batches and preferably only when the items are needed by the view. It sounds good, but I have no idea how to do that. Does anyone of you know a few examples in python codes? Unfortunately, I do not understand the C ++ examples. Or does anyone know a better solution?

Don't get me wrong. I don't want a ready solution because I'm too lazy. No! I want to learn and work on it.

Comment: [PyQt5 fetch more example](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/itemviews/fetchmore.py). If you want the PyQt4 version, [download the source](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download).

Comment: @ekhumoro; TA. The example only works with `QAbstractListModel()`, but in my project I am using `QStandardItemModel()`. Doesn't it matter?

Comment: @Sophus If you want to perform this task you should not use QStandardItemModel, you must create your custom class following that logic.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I am using `QTreeView()`and not `QListView()`. We know that `QAbstractListModel()`is created for `QListView`.

Comment: The examples also include the [simpletreemodel](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel) and the [editabletreemodel](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/itemviews/editabletreemodel), which show how to use a `QAbstractItemModel` as a tree. In fact, all 'official' examples have been ported to Python and are included in the PyQt source.

Comment: @titusjan: In general, Is `QStandardItemModel()` a bad idea to work with it?I always thought is a good idea to work with this model.

Comment: @Sophus. Have you done any actual profiling that proves there is a performance bottleneck? Or is this just a theoretical exercise? If the `QStandardItemModel` is working and does not cause any measurable problems, why bother changing it?

Comment: @ekhumoro: At the moment my project works fine. But just in terms of database I think ahead. In my database I have round about 12k records currently - and rising. In my project, all records are concurrently loaded into the `QStandardItemModel()` and view via `QTreeView ()`, as soon as I click the button named "Query data sets".  I want to spare the memory and therefore believe that my practice is wrong.

Comment: @Sophus. A simple improvement would be to only load child items on demand (i.e. when the parent is expanded). So the tree would initially just show the top-level items.

Comment: @ekhumoro: On my `QTreeView()`I don't use child items, just only top-level items. I use `QTreeView()`, because I am able to take multiple columns. `QListView()`doesn't support multiple columns.

Comment: @Sophus. Well in that case, use `QSqlTableModel` instead of `QStandardItemModel`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I don't want to be very dependent on PyQt, so I work with SQLAlchemy. Should I later, for whatever reason, change the user interface, I would have to adjust the database structure completely again. Too much effort.

Comment: @Sophus. Whatever suggestions are made, you just invent more new requirements that are not mentioned in your question. Please do some proper research of your own and come back with a more concrete question. Asking for examples is off-topic on SO, and the comments have proved that the rest of your question is far too broad and ill-defined.

Comment: @ekhumoro: TA for your help. I will come back later..